# Security evaluation during project management

Tags: security, project-management

Generally speaking.

How do a project manager evaluate and track the security issue for a project? Or is there any online resource that I can use as a reference ?

Comment: Candidate for moving to http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing whatsoever to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you would track this like everything else you track on your project.

Make sure that there is an architecture and project requirement review -- go though all aspect of the architecture and design and document any issues and questions as you go along.  Depending on your application, it may include securing external communication and communication between different parts of the application, and understand any possibilities for  malicious user input.  If your application store any data, review what data is stored, and ask "what would happen if the data was lost or leaked".   Understand how all sensitive data store is encrypted, and make sure that user passwords are *never* stored  (store a oneway hash instead).   Review how/if any encryption keys can be rotated, so that loss/leak of key does not mean compromise of security.

Document all issues and questions found in your favorite bug tracking and task management tool, even if just as reminder to get back and inspect actual implementation.

Comment: Thank you Soren. That did great help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you add them as 'risks' or 'tasks' in your ALM system, depending on which phase you are current in with respect to your project.

How to evaluate security issues is usually deferred first to Devs or IT Profs depending on the nature and then reported back to the PM for review.